# React Native 'require' statement resolves to a number when used in mapping

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-component, react-image

I understand that require('') needs a static string, but when I try to map values in packaging to be used later in code

```
const BOXES2 = {
  silver: require('../../assets/imgs/status/silveroutline.png'),
  gold: require('../../assets/imgs/status/goldoutline.png'),
  platinum: require('../../assets/imgs/status/platinumoutline.png')
}
```

they resolve to integers , the following logs the number 6

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    var data = BOXES2[this.props.userData.memberStatus];
    console.log(data);
  }
```

so then I cannot load images like this

```
<Image
        source={BOXES2[this.props.userData.memberStatus]}
        style={img}
        resizeMode="contain"
      />
```

memberStatus is a string value and the data and image paths are correct, as I can get it to work by creating a separate Image using each source path directly in render(), and then placing one of them in return() conditionally by the userData.

I would like to figure the other way out though, as it requires many many less lines and much easier to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

keep all require statements in seperate file like

**image.js**

```
export default {                                                                
  silver: require('../../assets/imgs/status/silveroutline.png'),
  gold: require('../../assets/imgs/status/goldoutline.png'),
  platinum: require('../../assets/imgs/status/platinumoutline.png')
};
```

and import this file in your screen like this:

```
import BOXES2 from 'src/config/Images';
```

after importing use image component like this:

```
 eg: <Image
         source={BOXES2[this.props.userData.memberStatus]}
         style={img}
         resizeMode="contain"
     />
```

Comment: It does work that way! Do you know why it works that way, but I cannot set them like I did just outside the class definition?

Comment: const BOXES2 = {
  back: require('src/images/back.png'),
  down : require('src/images/down.png'),
  listening: require('src/images/listener.gif'),
}
export default class Information extends Component { // your screen code }

Comment: it worked for me if i define outside of the class like above.

Comment: that's exactly what I had and it would return an integer when I called the mapped value.

Comment: do you whant to map over the BOXES2 object?

Comment: Yea I got it sort of figured out, if I put the file in the same folder so that the path is './images' it works fine. I just was hoping to not have an extra file in every component to have one object mapping two or three values

Comment: if you have more images in your project it is better to maintain seperate file and import that file and do mapping because infuture if you whant to add an image to your BOXES2 you can add into that file.

Comment: If this answer solve the problem. it would be better if you accept the answer thank u